# Change language of auto-generated labels in pivot tables

Tags: excel

I'm using Russian version of Excel.

In pivot tables, some auto-generated labels  in the field totals and filters use Russian words. For example, in the total row **Итог Available Nights** stands for **Total Available Nights**, and in the filter, **(Все)** stands for all items. I've sent the file to my client who uses English version, and he's seeing the same Russian words. I supposed those parts of pivot tables should adjust to pc's locale, but it seems they don't.

I've changed my OS language to English (US), but this doesn't help. When I open the file using Excel Online, it displays the same.

I need all parts of the pivot tables to be in English. Is there any possibility to do so?
For some unknown reason, I was able to change labels for grand totals, but not for specific subtotals.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Pivot table subtotal
[image]

Pivot table filter
[image]

Comment: Make sure your 'Region' Settings are properly set, and also your 'display language' setting. These are technically in different locations with Windows 10.

`Control Panel>Region` - To check the 'display language' click on the "Language Perference" link within the 'Region' panel.

Comment: @IrwinAllen13 My region setting is USA and display language is English (US). It doesn't help anyway. It seems like it's Excel interface language that matters, although if so, labels must change in English version.

Comment: Well then, that is how I was taught to change language settings with excel. Perhaps, check out the Language Setting under the "Excel Options" tab. I see that there are a few options there to adjust.